# React-Native Tab Bar: Remove horizontal line (React Native UI Kitten + React Navigation)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ui-kitten

Using the `react-native-ui-kitten` components `BottomNavigation` and `BottomNavigationTab` in my app running on iPhone (expo *v2.21.2*, `react-native` *v0.57.1* ), there is a horizontal line on the top of the currently selected `BottomNavigationTab` which contains both the title and an icon.

**From my app:**

*Test B* tab is selected and has the unwanted horizontal line above the icon.

[image]

**From the docs:**

The [`BottomNavigation` docs](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/components/bottom-navigation/overview#bottomnavigation) show that when both the title and icon are defined, there is no horizontal line on the selected tab. But this is not the case for me.

[image]

**Question:** How can the horizontal line be removed?

**My Code:**

```
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createStackNavigator, createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { BottomNavigation, BottomNavigationTab, BottomNavigationProps, Avatar } from 'react-native-ui-kitten';

class BottomNavigationShowcase extends React.Component {

    ... 

    render () {
        return (
            <BottomNavigation
                selectedIndex={this.state.selectedIndex}
                onSelect={this.onTabSelect}
            >
                <BottomNavigationTab title='Test A' icon={this.renderIconA} />
                <BottomNavigationTab title='Test B' icon={this.renderIconB} />
                <BottomNavigationTab title='Test C' icon={this.renderIconC} />
                <BottomNavigationTab title='Test D' icon={this.renderIconD} />
            </BottomNavigation>
        );
    }

}

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        TestA: TestAScreen,
        TestB: TestBScreen,
        TestC: TestCScreen,
        TestD: TestDScreen
    }, {
        initialRouteName: 'TestA',
        tabBarComponent: BottomNavigationShowcase
    }
)

const RootNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
    Main: TabNavigator,
}, {
    initialRoute: "Main"
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try to add a property to the `BottomNavigation`-component: `appearance='noIndicator'`. Looks like we've forgotten display this ability in the documentation. Hope this helps.